# How to read from a file into a dictionary as a list

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code so far...

```
class_1={}

if username in class_1:
    with open ('class1.txt') as f:
        for data in f:
            username, score = data.split(",")
            class_1[username].append(score)
else:
    with open ('class1.txt') as f:
        for data in f:
            username, score = data.split(",")
            class_1[username]=int(score)

print(class_1)
```

I am trying to read from a txt file that looks like this:

```
Alex,5
John,2
Ryan,1
Bill,9
```

I want the username and score to be put into a dictionary with a list so that if a user takes multiple tests, his scores save in a list like this:

```
class_1 {"Alex":[5,3,2,1,2],"John":[2,2,3,4,7] etc..}
```

I cant seem to do this and I have been trying for hours! Please help me in any way.

Answer (score 0):

As no_name suggested - defaultdict is more elegant

```
from collections import defaultdict

class_1 = defaultdict(list)
with open ('class1.txt') as f:
    for data in f:
        username, score = data.strip().split(",")
        class_1[username].append(score)
```

Comment: use defaultdict instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for such tasks :

```
>>> s="""Alex,5
... 
... John,2
... 
... Ryan,1
... 
... Bill,9
... 
... Alex,7
... 
... Alex,10
... 
... Bill,3
... 
... """
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for name,score in [i.split(',') for i in s.split('\n') if i]:
...     d[name].append(score)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Bill': ['9', '3'], 'John': ['2'], 'Alex': ['5', '7', '10'], 'Ryan': ['1']})
```

And in your case :

```
>>> for name,score in [line.split(',') for line in open('class1.txt') if line]:
...     d[name].append(score)
```

Comment: Why did you repeat the assignment (d=defaultdict, d=defaultdict(list))?

Comment: @no_name just a typo, ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some pythonic solution and use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) approach.

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

So what we are doing? We simple assume there is a key in this dictionary and there is an list where we can append score. And if there is no key, we just create this list with first score found.

Code would be:

```
scores={}
with open ('class1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        username, score = line.split(",")
        try:
            scores[username].append(score)
        except KeyError:
            scores[username] = [score]
```